# Q: If $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ then $f$ has a limit $\forall y \in R$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a problem and came up with a proof for the following:

Assume that $f: R \to R$ is such that $\forall x,y \in R: f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$.  If $f$ has a limit at $0$, prove that $f$ has a limit at every point and either $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1 \vee \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$.

I would appreciate any help on what I have written so far.

**Pf**

$\forall y \in R$, $\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = \lim_{x\to y} f(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x}{k}) $.  Letting $k\to \infty$ we have that 
$$\lim_{x\to y}f(x) = \lim_{x\to y} \lim_{k\to \infty}f(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{k}) \\
= \lim_{x\to y} \lim_{k\to \infty}f(\frac{x}{k})^{k}$$  Since $\lim_{k\to \infty} (\frac{x}{k})^{k} = 0$ then it must be that $\lim_{k\to \infty}f(\frac{x}{k})^{k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} L^{k}$

So the limit exists for every $y \in R$. Furthermore, we showed above that $$\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$ through the use of the given identity $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$.  Then $\lim_{k\to \infty} L^{k} = L$ and so $L = 1 \vee L = 0$.

$\Box$

Is my use of limits legal and correct here?

Comment: To be precise, you ought to have $\sum_{i=1}^kf(x/k)$, where the upper limit is $k$ and not infinity. Referring to the first sum you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of limits is not correct;  and you seem to be assuming that $ f $ is continuous, which is true but not a given hypothesis.  You also reach the conclusion that the function is constant (when you say that the limit at any $ y $ agrees with the limit at zero), which is not true as the example $ f (x)=e^x $ shows.

The way to use the hypothesis that the limit exists at zero is as follows: 
$$
f (x+h)-f (x)=f (x+h)-f (x+0)=f (x) f (h)-f (x) f (0)\\ =f (x)\, [f (h)-f (0)]\to f (x)\times0=0.
$$
This shows that $\lim_{x\to y} f (x)=f (y) $ for every $ y $, so the limit exists at every point, and moreover $ f $ is continuous at every point.

Finally,   $ f (0)=f (0+0)=f (0)^2$. So $ f (0)=0$ or $ f (0)=1$. And thus the limit at zero is either zero or one.

Comment: That should be -> f (x) x f (0), not f (x) x 0 in your first equation.

Comment: No, you are missing the point. We know that $f(h)-f(0)\to0$ when $h\to0$ by hypothesis ("the limit exists at $0$"). If it were $f(x)f(0)$, it would be a proof that the exponential is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the many mistakes. I've taken note of them!